# Server side processing issue Class SSP not found

Tags: php

I want to make a datatable with server side processing, but I receive that error message:

Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SSP' not found in ssp.php:45\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in ssp.php on line 45'

Can somebody help me to fix that issue?

Here are my codes:

```
<table class="table" id="manageMemberTable">                    
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Nom</th>
                            <th>Téléphone</th>                                                  
                            <th>Zone</th>
                            <th>Localisation</th>                               
                            <th>Mensualité</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

Here is the js code:

```
manageMemberTable = $("#manageMemberTable").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "php_action/ssp.php",
        "order": []
    });
```

server side script ssp.php

```
// Database connection info 
$dbDetails = array( 
    'host' => 'xxxx', 
    'user' => 'xxxx', 
    'pass' => 'xxxx', 
    'db'   => 'xxxx' 
); 
 
// DB table to use 
$table = 'clients'; 
 
// Table's primary key 
$primaryKey = 'id'; 
 
// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. 
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database.  
// The `dt` parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. 
$columns = array( 
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'nom',  'dt' => 1 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'tel',      'dt' => 2 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'zone',     'dt' => 3 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'localisation',    'dt' => 4 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'mensualite',    'dt' => 5 ), 
    
    
); 
 
// Include SQL query processing class 
require 'ssp.class.php'; 

$where = "entreprise_id='15' AND status !='supprime'";

// Output data as json format 
echo json_encode(SSP::simple( $_GET, $dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $where ));

?>
```

Comment: If this is a SQL issue, we need to see your SQL as well, and sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: @jarlh a php class not found error cannot be a result of an issue with mysql / sql code, unless the php files themselves are stored within mysql and retrieved from there. But then the require part would not work like this.

Comment: files are not stored within mysql, of course

Comment: @Shadow, It was a rhetorical question. (Thanks anyway!)

Comment: @jarlh it would have been simpler to remove the mysql tag as I did :)

Comment: Please I also have that message:  Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: Have you looked in 'ssp.class.php' to make sure there is a uppercase 'SSP' defined there? No typos or anything? And it's completely public?

Comment: dear @Oli the ssp.class.php file wasn't the good one. thks very much